# how to get the result on the basis of expire date

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento-1.5, magento

this is what i am trying to do ! i want to filter my results on the basis of end date mean if end date is less then the current date then display the result else do not.

```
public function getAllEvents() {

  $all_events = Mage::getModel('events/events')->getCollection()
       ->addAttributeToFilter('end_date', array('lt' => date(strtotime(getdate()),'YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))
       ->setOrder('start_date', 'ASC')
       ->getData();
  return $all_events;
}
```

but am getting this error on frontend when i try to get the result 
$this->getAllEvents();

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR 
please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a ) on the following line:

```
->addAttributeToFilter('end_date', array('lt' => date(strtotime(getdate()),'YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))
```

Add another ) and you should be all set.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Esol_Events_Model_Mysql4_Events_Collection::addAttributeToFilter()

Comment: Try addEntityToFilter instead of attribute

Comment: Now getting this :( 
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Esol_Events_Model_Mysql4_Events_Collection::addEntityToFilter()

Comment: It is looking to me like that you have setup your events module incorrectly. I would open that up in another question and close this one out (click the green checkbox next to the answer) since that is a pretty different issue (and potentially more complex) and this question was related to a different error message.